# Error populating ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, list, subclass, superclass

I have this code:

```
ObservableCollection<GuiQuestionCluster> clusters = new ObservableCollection<GuiQuestionCluster>(this.ExaminationViewModel.Examination.QuestionClusters);
```

So, `this.ExaminationViewModel.Examination.QuestionClusters` are of the type of `QuestionCluster`. `QuestionCLuster` is the superclass of `GuiQuestionCluster`. The code I wrote didn't work, it gives errors. But I want to know how I fix this, is there a little trick for it?

First error:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method
>   match for
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.ObservableCollection(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Second:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert
>   from
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Comment: Please provide specific error information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no trick to this, because of the type difference. Here are your options:

- Make it a QuestionClusters  collection rather than GuiQuestionClusters
- Use a foreach loop to add item to the list. You will have to create the object and assign value directly or use an overloaded constructor that takes the base class type. This is in principle not the best design as it can cause partial assignment.
- You can explore using inheritance or extension method to workaround this